# Display Menu Navigation Label

Tags: menus, navigation, title

How to get Navigation Label as should be of the menu

[image: What is the code for calling or echoing the navigation label of a menu item?]

I'm using this code

```
      <?php 
    $locations = get_registered_nav_menus();
    $menus = wp_get_nav_menus();
    $menu_locations = get_nav_menu_locations();

    $location_id = 'footer_menu1';

    if (isset($menu_locations[ $location_id ])) 
{ 
  foreach ($menus as $menu) 
  {

    if ($menu->term_id == $menu_locations[ $location_id ]) 
    {
      echo '<h2>'.$menu->name.'</h2>';
      // Get the items for this menu
      $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu);

      foreach ( $menu_items as $item )
      {

        $id = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu_item_object_id', true );
        $page = get_page( $id );
        //$link = get_page_link( $id ); ?>
  <li><a href="<?php echo $item->url; ?>" > <?php echo $page->post_title; ?> </a></li>
  <?php 
      }

      break;
    }
  }
    } 
    ?>
```

Thanks in advanced!

Can I replace `<?php echo $page->post_title; ?>` with `<?php echo $menu->nav_label; ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `$page->post_title;` with `$item->title;` to get the menu item's label